# How tall were the giant chess pieces in Harry Potter?

Tags: harry-potter

Rowling writes of the Harry, Ron, and Hermione in Chapter 16 of *Harry Potter and the Philosopher's Stone*,

> They were standing on the edge of a huge chessboard, behind the black chessmen, which were all taller than they were and carved from what looked like black stone.

How tall were the chess pieces?

I suspect the main evidence would come from the movie, assuming there isn't sufficient information in the novel. However, we can pick up a few things from the fact (for example) that Ron was able to mount the Knight's back. I guess the first thing would be to estimate or find out how tall

Comment: The chess pieces in the film won't necessarily be the same size they are in the book

Comment: It's hard to answer this, especially as a typical knight is not shaped like a real horse.

Comment: @SpacePhoenix as I said, the main evidence is likely to come from the film. I disagree that there is much chance of anything in the book explicitly contravening anything in the film; if it does, this would be worth noting. Presumably the book cannot be the primary source as there is nowhere near enough information (?). I thought this was all relatively clear from the OP

Comment: @Righter what exactly do you mean? You suspect the pieces as shown in the film don't have the same relative heights as standard chess pieces? In that case, a basic answer would estimate *one* of the heights and an excellent answer all of them (King, Queen, Bishop, Knight, Rook; it's clear the pawns are significantly smaller in the films than they should be).

Comment: @MobeusZoom No, I meant that the movie knights look like [this](https://imgur.com/Kd8Xl7P), while the knights you typically find in chess look like one of [these](https://imgur.com/4X1fm97). So the main hint you get from the books (that Ron could mount one of the horses) isn't very useful to estimate the height of the other pieces.

Comment: The correct answer comes from the source and is already included in the question; How tall? “Taller than they were.”

Answer (score 2):

### Greater than 143.5cm

In *The Philosopher's Stone* Ron is described as:

> tall, thin and gangling, with freckles, big hands and feet, and a long nose

Later, in the *Deathly Hallows*, he'll still be:

> long and lanky

So it seems that Ron is always above average height.

The [median height](https://www.healthline.com/health/when-do-boys-stop-growing#median-height) for an 11-year old, the age when Ron enters Hogwarts, is **56.4 in. (143.5 cm)**

Since Ron is frequently described as taller than those around him, the statues are probably greater than 143.5cm tall.

---

**In the movies, some were up to 12 feet tall**

As noted in the video below, some were very tall and heavy for the film:

https://fb.watch/aiPH207hKb/